# Squeeze/sandwich theorem for $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Is it possible to find the following using the squeeze/sandwich theorem?
Think of the

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$$

Comment: The inequalities here may help you

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Isn't $0\le \dfrac{n!}{n^n}\le \dfrac 1n?$

Comment: How do we know that n!/n^n<=1/n? I'm not disputing that it is, but would that need another proof? What's the justification for using that particular inequality?

Comment: $\dfrac{n!}{n^n}=\dfrac{n}{n}\dfrac{n-1}{n}\dots \dfrac{2}{n}\dfrac{1}{n}\le \dfrac{1}{n}$ because $\dfrac{n-k}{n}\le 1$ for any $k\in\{0,\cdots,n-1\}.$

Comment: Since $n^n$ is the product of $n$ $n$-times, and $n!$ is the product of $1\cdot2\cdots n$, both products have $n$ factors.  Pair up the factors.  Each factor of $n!$ is less than or equal to the corresponding factor of $n^n$, so you have a product of things less than or equal to $1$.  Moreover, since $n!$ has a factor of $1$, which matches with a factor of $n$, the entire product is less than or equal to $1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to apply the squeeze theorem.  However, you need more than the basic version.  In particular, you need the approximation

$$
\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{e^n}\leq n!\leq e\frac{n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{e^n}.
$$

Therefore, 
$$
\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{e^n}\leq\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{n^ne^n}\leq \frac{n!}{n^n}\leq e\frac{n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{n^ne^n}=e\frac{\sqrt{n}}{e^n}
$$

Now, study the terms on the end.

Note: mfl's comment is a simpler approach.

Comment: Notwithstanding the statement in this answer, [basic Stirling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $\log(n!)=n\log n-n+o(n)$ suffices to solve the question.